# Jquery - Get variable with string

Tags: jquery

I need to access a variable using a string. When calling `preSort` the last parameter is `"l"`. I need to use that "l" to get the `l` variable sent to `preSort` right after `t`.

preSort(t,`l(this var)`,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag,element,`"l(using this string)"`);

```
function preSort(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag,element,ident) {
    //var ident = getParameterByName(''+ident+'');
    toHtml = window[ident]; //this is blank
    if(toSort(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag) != false)
    {
        urlBuilder(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag)

    $(".refresh-"+element+"").remove();
    $("#sort-filter-"+element+"").append('<button id="'+ident+'" class="refresh refresh-'+element+' align-left btn btn-primary btn-sm">'+toHtml+' <i class="fa fa-times right"></i></button>');

    }
}

        $("#letter").change(function() {
        var t = getTab();
        var l = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var s = getParameterByName('s');
        var y = getParameterByName('y');
        var p = getParameterByName('p');
        var n = getParameterByName('n');
        var c = getParameterByName('c');
        var co = getParameterByName('co');
        var search = getParameterByName('q');
        var tag = getParameterByName('tag');

        $("#"+t).empty();
        var element = $(this).attr("id");

        preSort(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag,element,"l");
    /*
        if(toSort(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag) != false)
        {
            urlBuilder(t,l,p,n,y,c,co,s,search,tag)

            $(".refresh-letter").remove();
            $("#sort-filter-letter").append('<button id="l" class="refresh refresh-letter align-left btn btn-primary btn-sm">'+l+' <i class="fa fa-times right"></i></button>');
        }
    */
    });
```

Comment: It's a long stroy. I have a bunch of dropdowns which can be used together. So I need the other dropdown values to build a query.

Comment: Ok ... so if I can pass its value to preSort ... I need to use that last parameter "l"(L) to access it. On other changes that last "l" will be a "y" or "n"

Comment: Yes ... the "l" will be used as an id ... which works ... but I can't get the value.

Comment: Button looks like this now `<button id="l" class="refresh refresh-letter align-left btn btn-primary btn-sm"> NO L VALUE <i class="fa fa-times right"></i></button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract from chat:
more specific question:

**How to access a variable in a function, that should reference a definition in a functions head**

```
function f(a,b,c,d,e,f,ident){
    var value = this[ident];  // this[ident] is undefined, no access to variable name
     alert(value);
}

f(111,222,333,4,5,6, 'c'); // should alert param 'c' = 333 --> undefined
f(111,222,333,4,5,6, 'c'); // should alert param 'f' = 6 --> undefined
```

I don't know a way to access the arguments by their variable name.

**Workaround:**
Instead of a letter/variable name, pass the index of the argument in function call.

```
function f(a,b,c,d,e,f,position){
    var value = arguments[position - 1];  //  -1 as array start with index 0
     alert(value);
}

f(111,222,333,4,5,6, 3); // should alert 3rd param = 333 --> ok
f(111,222,333,4,5,6, 6); // should alert 6th param = 6 --> ok
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access a variable using a string

You can access variables by *name*, by *dot notation* or by *brackets* (because variables will be a property of the current object/function, at top level the window-object).

```
var helloVar = "hello";
// get by variable name
var a = helloVar;
// get by dot notation
var b = this.helloVar;
// get by brackets passing a string within ""
var c = this["helloVar"]; <-- this one may help you
```

a,b,c all access the same variable value

Comment: I tried like thisL `var toHtml = this[""+ident+""];` and like this: `var toHtml = this[ident];` and this `var toHtml = this.ident;`  but no luck.

Comment: They re all initialized on a change action. and then passed to the preSort function.

Comment: I added a bit more code. I need to simplify my code a bit ... it's getting too big. But I don't know how to access that parameter ...